# Get query string using onsubmit event

Tags: javascript, ajax, onsubmit

I want to convert a form submission to ajax request. Here is my code:

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="iso8859-9">
<script>

  document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function(event) {

    document.getElementById("query_form").onsubmit = function(event) {
        console.log(event);
        return false;
    }
  });
</script>
</head>

<body>
<form action="query.php" id="query_form" method="get">
<input name="first">
<input name="second">
<button type="submit">
</form>
<table id="results"></table>
</body>
</html>
```

Can I just read calculated query string in onsubmit event to use it with ajax, or do I need to create it myself using javascript. I don't want to use external library if possible.

Answer (score 0):

> Can I just read calculated query string in onsubmit event to use it with ajax

No.

> do I need to create it myself using javascript

Yes.

A general solution will involve looping over event.target.elements, collection name/value pairs while filtering out fieldsets, disabled elements, unchecked checkboxes/radiobuttons, handling multiple selects correctly and then passing all the results though `encodeURIComponent(name) + "=" + encodeURIComponent(value)` before joining on `&`.